# How can i create a query for add to cart with WebSQL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-sql

I'm having trouble creating queries. I'm not good to create queries for WebSQL. Can you help me create a query for add to cart function?

below is the code I have created :

CartService.js :

```
angular.module('ecommerce').factory('CartService',
    ['$webSql', '$http', '$q', 'urls',
        function ($webSql, $http, $q, urls) {

            var factory = {
                addToCart: addToCart,
                removeCart: removeCart
            };

            function addToCart (id, name, price) {
                //my problem to create some query for WebSQL
            }

            return factory;]
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: *my problem to create some query for WebSQL* This will totally depend on your local database schema.

Comment: I use mysql database sir. _[MySQL Local Database](https://anotepad.com/notes/mpxdpq)_

Comment: What?? then why did you tagged `websql` to your question and even mentioned webql in your question's description?

Comment: I use websql only for cart sir

Comment: so, then why tell us that you use mysql ? You need help in websql or mysql?

Comment: i need help in websql sir